# Black hole absorbing photons?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, temperature, thermal-radiation, absorption

If a black hole has a radius that is not that much smaller than the wavelength of light emitted by the sun, and is at the same temperature, shouldn't it be able to absorb photons as well as emit them? Is there a way to calculate the rate of photon absorption by a black hole?

Comment: Do you want to ask whether black holes can absorb photons? I mean is there a reason as to why you think they should not?

Comment: I'm more asking if there's a way to calculate the rate at which they absorb photons

Comment: I'm in photonics and not black-hole physics, bot does black holes come in such sizes ?